# Get date based on days in sqlite, get past 7 dates and future 14 dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

we need past 7 dates and future 14 dates from below table

Days table

| ID | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Sunday |
| 3 | Tuesday |
| 9 | Wednesday |
| 10 | Friday |
| 8 | Thursday |
| 4 | Saturday |

now we're fetching future 7 dates based on current date

```
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN D.Day='Sunday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0')
           WHEN D.Day='Monday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 1')
           WHEN D.Day='Tuesday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 2')
           WHEN D.Day='Wednesday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 3')
           WHEN D.Day='Thursday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 4')
           WHEN D.Day='Friday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 5')
           WHEN D.Day='Saturday' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 6')
       END AS WeekDate
FROM Days AS D
```

but now we need to get past 7 dates and future 14 dates from current date based on above table

Answer (score 0):

What you do is right, and the solution is fairly simple.

```
select      date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0', '-14 days') as 'Sunday2weeks',
date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0', '-7 days') as 'Last Sunday',  
date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0') as 'Next Sunday'
```

For today (2021-05-26) it returns

```
Sunday2weeks    Last Sunday    Next Sunday
2021-05-16      2021-05-23     2021-05-30
```

This works because [according to SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you can use zero *or more* modifiers. The order is important.

From here it should be fairly straightforward to modify your query.

EDIT:

Something like this ??

```sql
SELECT 
       CASE
           WHEN D.X='SUN' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0')
           WHEN D.X='MON' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 1')
           WHEN D.X='TUE' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 2')
       END AS WeekDate,

       CASE
           WHEN D.X='SUN' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
           WHEN D.X='MON' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 1', '-7 days')
           WHEN D.X='TUE' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 2', '-7 days')
       END AS LastWeek,

       CASE
           WHEN D.X='SUN' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0', '+14 days')
           WHEN D.X='MON' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 1', '+14 days')
           WHEN D.X='TUE' THEN date('now', 'localtime', 'weekday 2', '+14 days')
       END AS Plus2Weeks
       
FROM B AS D

--- returns for 26.may 2021

WeekDate    LastWeek    Plus2Weeks
-----------------------------------
2021-05-30  2021-05-23  2021-06-13
2021-05-31  2021-05-24  2021-06-14
2021-06-01  2021-05-25  2021-06-15
```